# Однородны ли прилагательные и нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Красивый (?) мёртвый замок из песка

Comment: А можно привести контекст?  Прилагательные плохо сочетаются друг с другом при любых отношениях между ними,  однородных или неоднородных. Логичнее сказать так: красивый, но мертвый замок из песка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прилагательные **неоднородны**: *мёртвый* - классификационный признак (так никто не живёт, он ненастоящий, это имитация), а *красивый* - качественный признак. Запятая, соответственно, не нужна.